# Programming Perl 5th Edition Chapter 4 Exercises

Tags: perl

the exercise has you build two subroutines.. &average (which computes the average of a list of numbers) and &above_average (which will print out the numbers in the list that are greater than the average).

The answer they give for the above_average sub is:

```
sub above_average
{ my $average = average(@_);
  my @list;
 foreach my $element (@_) {
 if ($element > $average ){
    push @list, $element;
    }
   }
 @list;
}
```

And the accompanying text asks "Why is the control variable $element used instead of Perl's favorite default $_?"

Why is that?  I actually wrote my answer using $_ and it seemed to work.. so I'm curious why the author feels the need to highlight that he used $element instead of $_.

Thanks!

Comment: This post is also very informative on the subject: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=641994

Comment: 5th Edition? The latest I have (and the latest shown [here](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596004927.do)) is the 4th edition.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out those other posts

Comment: Keith.. I think they are actually up to a 6th edition now.. http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920018452.do

Comment: In this particular example, there is no reason to prefer one over the other. Alternatively, you can use any excuse you like to prefer one over the other.

Comment: The book you are talking about is `Learning Perl` not `Programming Perl`. In this particular example I think the emphasis is more on readability rather than functionality.